# how to route to other page when we use CustomButtonIcon in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
  Expanded(
            child: CustomButtonIcon(
              action: () {},
              iconPath: "assets/images/ic_eksplor.png",
              text: "Eksplor",
              fontColor: MyColors.white,
              height: 33,
              width: 33,
              isBold: true,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, wouldn't it just add Navigator push to the button action?

Comment: done. but still not work for me

Comment: I believe you should follow the flutter tutorial for navigating between screens here [https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics).

Answer (score 1):

```
Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                  Navigation commmand to which page you want to redirected it. 
                },
                child: CustomButtonIcon(
                  action: () {},
                  iconPath: "assets/images/ic_eksplor.png",
                  text: "Eksplor",
                  fontColor: MyColors.white,
                  height: 33,
                  width: 33,
                  isBold: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```